# Static methods with __construct

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor, static-methods

I need to use static methods with `__construct()` method to instantiate the `Client` object but the as far as I know there is no way to use the `__construct()` since the object is not instantiated when using static methods.

I thought I can use an init method.

```
class API
{

    static $client;

    public static function init()
    {
        $settings = [
            'username' => 'user1',
        ];

        self::$client = new Client($settings);
    } 

    public static function foo( )
    {
        self::$client->action('Foo text');
    }

}

API::init();
```

Then I can load the above class in other places and do the below.

```
API::foo();
```

**My Questions:**

1. Is there anything wrong with the way I wrote the class?
2. Does the above codes cause performance issue?
3. Is there any better way?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an approach this method is fine, but to be more [SOLID](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) here I would pass `Client` in `init()` function like `init(Client $client)` rather than instantiating it right in class. So do and `$settings`, better pass as an argument or preserve in some `private` variable rather than hardcoding in initializer.

It refers to **[D](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)** and **[L](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)** letter, the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

No performance issues, but only an architectural approach. But as to me I don't see any preconditions here for avoiding constructor and use `$api = new API($client, $settings);` rather than static invocation.

And constructor (*or initializer*) signature would look like

```php
public function __construct(Client $client, array $settings);
```